# Opencart - Remove items on specific pages?

Tags: php, module, opencart

I'm working on my opencart theme, but i encountered a problem.

I have my featured module displayed on both the home and category (see screenshots).

Screenshots:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIBaD.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkXwp.png

Now, i only want to hide the rating of items in the category layout, so it won't screw up my design/loose space. Is there a simple way to hide the rating on certain layouts? i.e. vqmod?

Removing:

```
      <? } ?>
      <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
      <div class="box-product-rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="box-product-rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-0.png"/></div>
      <?php } ?>
```

from: /var/www/html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl gives the desired results, but also removes the rating on the home layout.

Comment: I don't want to remove it completely from the category page, just from the module "featured" on the category page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a category page the URL contains a query string parameter/variable `path`.

It should be enough to check that this parameter is present and do not display the rating in that case:

```
  <?php if ($product['rating'] && !isset($_GET['path'])) { ?>
  <div class="box-product-rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

This is a simple workaround solution, could be achieved in *nicer* way from within featured module controller:

```
$this->data['is_category_page'] = isset($this->request->get['path']);
```

In template instead:

```
      <?php if ($product['rating'] && !$is_category_page) { ?>
  <div class="box-product-rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's been mind-boggling to get this to work!
Will try it out in an instant!

Comment: This works splendidly! Now i only need to display <div class="box-product-rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-0.png"/></div> when no ratings are found. I tried to add a else tag, but that didn't work (obviously).

Comment: Shadyyx, is it also possible to show another image, when no rating is found?